# ResourceNotFound Exception

Tags: resources

I am getting this ResourceNotFound Exception even though my code runs fine and exits onCreate.

```
public class MessageSelectionListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_selection_list);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    //My code
    //Create a temporary loading bar while the Uri loads
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.smsListView);
    mListView.setEmptyView(progressBar);

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    root.addView(progressBar);

    //List item population mechanism
    Cursor cursorSms = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    String[] fromColumns = {cursorSms.getColumnName(2), cursorSms.getColumnName(11)};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.item_title, R.id.item_body};

    this.mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.smsListView, cursorSms, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
    this.mListView.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_selection_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/"), null, null, null, null );
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

The Logcat messages are as follows:

04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090006 type #0x12 is not valid
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.newView(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:106)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:252)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1536)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:718)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:775)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1366)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I am using code from a lot of different sources and stringing things together, so I know I am doing something wrong, but I cant seem to find it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

The Resource file for the Activity is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MessageSelectionListActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/smsPageTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sms_page_title"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/smsPageInstructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/smsPageTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/smsPageTitle"
    android:text="@string/sms_page_instructions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/makeExcelFileButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/smsPageInstructions"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/smsPageInstructions"
    android:text="@string/make_excel_file" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/smsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/makeExcelFileButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/makeExcelFileButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/smsPageInstructions" />
```

And for the row layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" 
android:padding="6dip" >

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/item_check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_check_box"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/item_body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_check_box"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The code you provided is not relevant - it is not mentioned in the stack trace. The problem is somewhere in your XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix the problem.

here is how. The first message in the trace gave me the clue.
04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-08 13:06:49.699: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090006 type #0x12 is not valid

The the resource with ID 0x7f090006 is invalid. so when I traced it back to the code, I had used the Resource ID instead of the resource name (R.layout.XXXXXX). changing it to that resolved the issue.